# Smallest representation of data?

Tags: java

I'm sorry in advance if this question is really weird. I am sending data to a queue that I don't want duplicate data sent to. The program has no way of preventing duplicate data items and just accepts them but I believe the queue ID have to be unique and I can specify those myself.  So I want to try  to make my ID generated based on the data I'm sending.

Say I have two string:

```
hello, SO how are you? //base case
hello, SO how are you? //same
hello, SO how are You? //different, notice the capital Y
What up, SO! //completely different
```

What can I convert it to in Java that would match the first two strings above but make the other two unique?  I haven't tried much so far(because I'm not sure exactly what is the best thing to convert it to), but I did play around a bit with `GZIPOutputStream` but the size seemed kind of similar and I wasn't sure if it was the most efficient(i.e. smallest size like some crazy hex character or something).

I hope someone understands what I'm asking but if not, let me know and I'll try my best to clarify.

*Edit: sorry, Didn't just want something for strings, I'm dealing with lists(and maybe dictionaries) also. sorry about that*

Thanks

CODE:

```
public class hashtest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        convert("hello world"); //same
        convert("hello world"); //same

        convert("hello world!"); //exclamation mark
        convert("hello World"); //capital W

        convert_list(new int[] {5, 2, -3}); //same
        convert_list(new int[] {5, 2, -3}); //same
        convert_list(new int[] {5, 3, -3}); //different
        convert_list(new int[] {5, 2, -4}); //different

    }

    private static void convert_list(int[] is) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("word is " + is);
        System.out.println("hashcode is " + is.toString());
        System.out.println("****");
    }

    private static void convert(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("word is " + string);
        System.out.println("hashcode is " + string.hashCode());
        System.out.println("****");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use the `String` itself as the queue ID, or if you need an `Integer` use [`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)  (`hashCode()` returns the same value for the same characters)

#### Edited:

If your object is not actually a String, the best approach is to implement your own `hashCode()` method. Or for a "quick and dirty" you can simply render it as a String (make up a unique String out of the unique bits) and invoke String's hashCode() on that.

#### Edited (more):

The problem is you are using the `.toString()` of an array, which in java isn't implemented for the array class, so it falls back to the implementation for Object, which will be unique for every array, even if the contents are the same.

Fortunately, the JDK has provided the answer: Use the utility method [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))

```
private static void convert_list(int[] is) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("word is " + is);
    System.out.println("hashcode is " + Arrays.toString(is));
    System.out.println("****");
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is what I was getting at.  Hadn't noticed the String method before.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is good.  Sorry I wasn't totally clear. I was using String as an example but was going for a bit of a general solution.  With Strings it seems to work but when I test with lists, I seem to get different int with the same lists

Comment: Is there something that works for different kinds of data? upon looking further, I think this has something to do with lists, even if I convert them to strings they look different(I thought I could convert it to a string then to hash code) but the lists are the same I copy/pasted it.

Comment: Thanks, converting to a string then hash code doesn't work.  I'll post my code in the answer to show you what I'm doing.

Comment: Wow that worked( using Arrays.toString(is).hashCode() ).  I am sure you hear this a lot but your a genius!  I'm wondering is there any chance the numbers would be the same for different data or is this completely impossible?

Comment: I also realized Arrays.hashCode(is) works as well(number seems to be smaller also..)

Comment: Note that the *order* of elements changes the hashCode of an array, so to be consistent, you should *first* call `Arrays.sort(is);` *before* getting the hashCode, if it is your intention that element order should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that works not only with `String` you can choose the [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) algorithm.

In java you can use in in this way

```
MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
crypt.reset();
byte[] buf = crypt.digest("hello, SO how are you?".getBytes());
```

It works with bytes array, so you can convert your type in byte[] and then use it.

The result is a `byte[]` of length 20. So it is a good choice if your original data length is greater then 20 bytes.

And about the probability that two different input produce the same results read this [post](http://theblogthatnoonereads.davegrijalva.com/2009/09/25/sha-1-collision-probability/). Or search more technical material on the web. In any case the probability is very very low.

Comment: Thanks Dash1e, I'll play around with this and test it.